# Working with a checkbox and EntityFieldQuery

Tags: entities

So I have a custom field which is a checkbox and is called 'field_hide_panel'.

The on value is '1' and the off value is '0'. But bare in mind, this field was added later so there are a lot of rows in my database which will not have any field_hide_panel value.

When this checkbox is selected it should be omitted from the results of my query.

I have this line to try to achieve this:

```
$query->fieldCondition('field_hide_panel','value', '1', '!=');
```

The problem is, I'm not getting anything returned. I think this is because most of my nodes don't have a 'field_hide_panel' value at all but I still want these returned as my logic says these should still show because field_hide_panel does not equal 1.

Is there any way around this without me having to go through hundreds of nodes and re-save them so they get '0' as the field_hide_panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add tag to your query and use [hook_query_TAG_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7) to add additional conditions. Here's an example:

```
function mymodule_get_nodes() {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->addTag('node_is_not_tagged');
  return $query->execute();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter().
 */
function mymodule_query_node_is_not_tagged_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_hide_panel', 'hp', 'node.nid = hp.entity_id AND hp.entity_type = :entity_type');
  $or = db_or()
    ->condition('hp.field_hide_panel', 0)
    ->isNull('hp.field_hide_panel');
  $query->condition($or);
}
```

Link to relative issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/1157006

Comment: Thanks, had to change a it a little to get it working but got me on the right track:

->condition('hp.field_hide_panel', 0)
->isNull('hp.field_hide_panel');

Comment: oh, you are right, fixed.